# How to put both image and text in the same div without messing with alignment

Tags: html, css, image, html-heading

HTML

```
<div id="heading">Red Tailed Hawk</div>
<div id="panelpic1"></div>
```

CSS

```css
#panelpic1{
    content: url(file:///C:/Users/Mohit/Desktop/images.jpg);
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    vertical-align: middle;  
}
#heading{
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 48px;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of alignment problem]

I want to align the heading and the image on the left of it.

When i put the heading and the image in the same div, it loses its alignment. How to fix that?

Comment: Please elaborate what you want?

Comment: the image of eagle head in the top of the web page i want it inside the top panel and not to overlapwith the content below. i also want to put the heading text in the middle of the top panel vertically @divy3993

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the panel pic div inside the heading div like this.

```
<div id="heading" ><div id="panelpic1"></div>Red Tailed Hawk</div>
```

Comment: This works . thanks but how do i vertically align the heading to be in the middle.

Comment: No worries try `line-height: 75px;` for #heading{} might need to be a greater value like 150px

Comment: No worries bud :)